# How can I tell what edition / variant of ABP my application is built on?

Tags: abp

I've inherited an application, whose origins are lost in the mists of time. It's fairly obvious, based on DLL references and database tables, that the application is based on some edition / variant of ASP.NET Boilerplate. The question is exactly which one? The possibilities (I know of) are:

- ASP.NET Boilerplate (free, open source)
- ABP Framework (free, open
  source)
- ASP.NET Zero (licensed, source provided)
- ABP Commercial
  (licensed, source provided)

Whatever I have, it's obviously an old version since it's running on .NET Framework. (Latest versions of all of these application frameworks run on .NET Core.) We are working toward a phased transition to .NET Framework on .NET Core but one of the first things I picked up on is the incompatibility of my existing database structures for account authentication with the latest ABP Framework. One of the prerequisites for a phased transition is that a single database repository should accommodate account authentication from both the legacy system (as it does today) and the new system we are going to start constructing. I'd like to start working on various alternatives to bridge the gap from "here" to "there" but I'm handicapped by not even knowing where "here" is. I do know that the existing application is based on some variant of ASP.NET Boilerplate, but there are at least four of those. If you can help me pinpoint exactly what I've got, that will be immensely helpful. Thanks!

(All application ABP references are to DLLS. We don't have any ABP source code which might be useful for identification purposes.)

[image]

Here is a snapshot of the database tables, if that helps to make the identification:

[image]

Here is the one row within the abpEditions table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages with the Abp prefix belong to ASP.NET Boilerplate or ASP.NET Zero. Packages with the Volo.Abp prefix belong to the ABP Framework or ABP Commercial. Since you have the Abp.Zero package, it appears to belong to ASP.NET Zero. The version information also appears to be 4.0.

Comment: If I upgrade our legacy application to the latest version of ASP.NET Zero for .NET Framework and create a new application based on the latest version of ASP.NET Zero for .NET Core, will those two applications be able to use the same common set of ABP database tables?